# Can you set timeout for every views on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, view

For example if a `TextView` or `RadioButton` is showing up on screen & after 10 seconds we want to show up some other `TextView` or `RadioButton` automatically. How to do that?

Comment: Why not please use handler for 10 second

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and after 10 second below method is called and then you change your textview according to your requirement :

```
   static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 10000; // Declear variable

   // Code in activity or fragment
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over              
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Comment: // 'Code in activity' part we have to paste the code for the view that we want to display first?
// And in This method is executed when the timer is over I have to paste the view that I want to execute after the time out na??

Comment: yes exactly you call this method when activity starts and after delay of 10 second this method run and then you change your textview text.

Comment: And if I have to repeat this several times I mean after the timeout a view & after that one more time out and one more view & after that one more ...for this what I need to change in the code ??

Comment: I have to display 10 different text view each have interval gap of 10 sec
Means first text view then after 10 sec second text view after 10 sec third text view and ....this continues till 10 th textview ....how your concept work here can u please explain it clearly I'm totally a beginner in android !

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountDownTimer to change layout when each 10s
this sample:

```
private void countDownTimer(){
 //10000 = 10s
 new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 }

 public void onFinish() {
  //Done 10s: code to change layout this
  //And call this again
  countDownTimer()
  }
 }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
textView.setText("Your old text");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText("Your new text");
        }
    }, 10 * 1000);
```